# fetch list change column name

Tags: java, ebean

```
String sql = "select name as firstName from user ";
SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
List list = sqlQuery.findList();
```

when I get list in list **firstName** is changed to **firstname** . but in my console query is same as above return why ?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation lower cases to take out issue where the DB Dictionary case is different (some are mixed, some upper, some lower) and SqlQuery internally uses the DB dictionary via DatabaseMetaData to load the SqlRow instances.

The List is actually a List ... and SqlRow is map like with get that handles that case issue.